# Get return true values using if else statements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

I want to get `true` values from the `if/else` statement using jQuery. I apply this code but I can't get the required output. It displays both `true` and `false` values.

```js
$.each(response, function(index, value) {
  var user = (user_id == value.User_id);

  if (user_roll == 'Customer' && user) {
    if (user === true) {
      //alert(user === true);       
      html += "<tr data-id='" + value.ticket_id + "'>";
      html += "<td>" + value.ticket_id + "</td>";
      html += "<td>" + value.User_id + "</td>";
      html += "<td>" + value.User_name + "</td>";
      html += "<td>" + value.Customer_name + "</td>";
      html += "<td>" + value.subject + "</td>";
      html += "<td>" + value.priority + "</td>";
    }
  }
```

The response is this : [The response I got][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oePac.png . I want to get only User_id = 1 records

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(user_id, value.User_id);`?

Comment: `if(user_roll == 'Customer' && user)` already means `user` is true (or truthy). You don't need to test a second time for `if(user === true)`

Comment: I tried this if(user_roll == 'Customer' && user) this also. But it doesn't work. In those two ways returns the same result.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What outptut does this code create and what output do you **want** to create?

Comment: And when you say *"it doesn't work"* you aren't explaining what is different than expected

Comment: This code shows all the value.User_id but, it not shows  user_id = value.User_id values.  I want to get when user_id = value.User_id values.

Comment: can u post the sample `response` and expected output with an example.

Comment: {ticket_id: 33, User_id: "1", User_name: "manesha"}
{ticket_id: 34, User_id: "1", User_name: "manesha"}
{ticket_id: 35, User_id: "2", User_name: "ishara"}
{ticket_id: 38, User_id: "5", User_name: "employee1"}
{ticket_id: 39, User_id: "2", User_name: "ishara"}
{ticket_id: 40, User_id: "1", User_name: "manesha"}
{ticket_id: 41, User_id: "4", User_name: "Silva"}
 {ticket_id: 43, User_id: "1", User_name: "manesha",}                                                       This is the output I got. But I want to get only User_id = 1 results.

Comment: [edit] the question to add additional code so it can be properly formatted

Answer (score -2):

try comparing the string values together. Sometimes what happens is one of the id that you pass is read as String.

So ,

```
user_id.toString() == value.User_id.toString()
```

this is what I do in Javascript to compare id, please check how to convert into String in jquery.

Comment: jQuery has nothing to do with type conversions

Comment: NO , I thought that maybe the user that it is getting by comparison might have some issues in it.